# From WDSL to java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I've been tasked with querying a soap client in java and i'm a bit confused as how to move forward.

The first thing i did was use the [Wizdler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb?hl=en) chrome plugin to prototype my SOAP request.  The soap "envelop" must be of this format I believe for it to work.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<Body>
    <GetMyProjectCharges xmlns="http://COMPANY.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges">
        <Employee>[string?]</Employee>
        <FiscalYear>[string?]</FiscalYear>
        <ApiKey>[string?]</ApiKey>
        <AppName>[string?]</AppName>
    </GetMyProjectCharges>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Next I've gone through some various tutorial as how to build a soap envelop in java but i keep getting into a strange situation where i'm getting `<SOAP-ENV:` prefixes on everything and when i take the generated envelop and try to paste it into the chrome plugin it doesn't work.

So I'm wondering where I go from here?  I realize soap is a pretty heavy protocol and so maybe that is what is confusing me but what I'm looking to do (for now) is:

1) Generate a soap request in java that matches the format above, and print out the results.

I understand i "might" have the option of Maven or some program to generate some class files for me from the WDSL but I'm not exactly sure what i do with that either.  Thanks!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you define what does not work? The prefixes might be all right. The XML that you've pasted tells a processor that all XML elements belong to the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`. A prefix can exist but might not be needed. If there is an error, post the stack trace here.

Comment: I don't get the point. do you have problems to deliver a soap message to your server or do you have problems on the server? for the former one i would recommend to use SoapUI for the later I would need more details

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got the point. Anyway I think you need to have the correct namespace for your soap messages. A blank SOAP message would look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So in your case I think this should work:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>

    <GetMyProjectCharges xmlns="http://COMPANY.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges">
        <Employee>[string?]</Employee>
        <FiscalYear>[string?]</FiscalYear>
        <ApiKey>[string?]</ApiKey>
        <AppName>[string?]</AppName>
    </GetMyProjectCharges>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But normally you use a namespace in the payload as well (which means *GetMyProjectCharges* would be something like *jeef:GetMyProjectCharges*).

Watch the 2nd namespace in the root tag

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:jeef="http://COMPANY.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>

    <jeef:GetMyProjectCharges>
        <jeef:Employee>[string?]</jeef:Employee>
        <jeef:FiscalYear>[string?]</jeef:FiscalYear>
        <jeef:ApiKey>[string?]</jeef:ApiKey>
        <AppName>[string?]</jeef:AppName>
    </jeef:GetMyProjectCharges>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To parse the SOAP messages it would be a good choice to use some wsdl to objects conversion tool. There are maven plugins for this as you already found out. To process the SOAP messages it would be worth to take a look at [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html).

Note: namespaces are defined by `xmlns:whatever="http://some.url.to.a.model/"`.

Comment: How do a chang the `soapenv` namespace ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two way to do a soap request.

**Solution 1**

If you use netbeans as code IDE, you have to create a project,  right click on a package and choose New >> Web Service Client. Insert the url of the soap endpoint and click ok. If you have jax-ws/Metro extension installed in your ide netbeans will generate all necessary classes to invoke the service programmatically. (ask me if you have troubles)

**Solution 2**

you could realize a soap request using simply javax.xml

```
private SOAPMessage invoke(QName serviceName, QName portName,
        String soapActionUri) throws Exception {

    Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
    service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointUrl);

    Dispatch dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName,
            SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);

    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(Dispatch.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean(true));
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(Dispatch.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, soapActionUri);

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

    Source source = new DOMSource(getQueryString());
    soapPart.setContent(source);

    message.saveChanges();

    System.out.println(message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getTextContent());

    SOAPMessage response = (SOAPMessage) dispatch.invoke(message);

    return response;
}

private Node getQueryString() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<soapenv:Envelope");
    // create your body
    builder.append("</soapenv:Body>");
    builder.append("</soapenv:Envelope>");

    DocumentBuilderFactory docfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docbuilder = docfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document stringDocument = docbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(builder.toString())));

    return stringDocument;
}
```

and to call the service use

```
String targetNameSpace = "your target namespace";
QName serviceName = new QName(targetNameSpace, "your service name");
QName portName = new QName(targetNameSpace, "Your port name");
String SOAPAction = "your soap action";
SOAPMessage response = invoke(serviceName, portName, SOAPAction);
if (response.getSOAPBody().hasFault()) {
     System.out.println(response.getSOAPBody().getFault());
}
```

P.S. forgive me for my english :(

Comment: So I got #1 working in a standalone netbeans project - but not maven.  How do i actually make a soap request though with the generated code?

Comment: @Jeef i've answered you again :)

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff you have to do something like this :

```
MyWebService service = new MyWebService(new Url(wsdlStringEndpoint));
Port port = service.getHttpsoap11port();
port.makerequest();
```

I've wroted a genericall call to make you understand how it should look. If you have some problems ask again (the code is a sample code)